# Iterate through the array and generate a new variable for each element

Tags: salesforce, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a JSON array stored in a variable which looks like below

```
{
  "Opportunity": {
    "QuoteLineItems": {
      "QuoteLineItem": {
        "ServiceTypeCode": "CC",
        "PhaseLevel": "1",
        "Quantity": "1",
        "UnitPrice": "2,854.50",
        "InvoicedSinceLast": "0.00",
        "LevelItems": {
          "LevelItem": {
            "PhaseLevelItemNumber": "R072",
            "DocumentNotes": {
              "Note": null
            }
          }
        },
        "Colonies": {
          "ColonyStage": {
            "QuoteColonyLineNumber": "1",
            "StageItems": {
              "StageItem": {
                "StageLineProperty": "CHARGE",
                "StageQuoteItemNumber": "ICM_033",
                "DocumentNotes": {
                  "Note": null
                }
              }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "QuoteLineItem": {
```

I need to iterate through each of the QuoteLineItem and generate a new json variable for each Item  so I am using the For each element like below

[image]

Inside the For each I am having a transform Messgae to generate a new json like below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
   "productCode" : //Not sure how to access the ServiceTypeCode on the QuoteLineItem 
   "axSequenceNumber" : vars.counter,
}
```

How do I get the ServiceTypeCode  for each QuoteLineItem in the transform message inside the for each loop. I a new to Mulesoft and any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QuoteLineItem is an object, not an array, so you can't use it to iterate. Instead you can use the [multi-value selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-selectors) to retrieve all matching keys as an array and use that to iterate:

```
  <foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload.Opportunity.QuoteLineItems.*QuoteLineItem]">
```

Inside the foreach you receive each element of the input array as the payload:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
   "productCode" : payload.ServiceTypeCode
   "axSequenceNumber" : vars.counter
}
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly by storing that into a variable. You should consider if a single transform may not achieve the same results.

Comment: I have to call an sys end point for each of the `QuoteLineItem` to create records in Salesforce. Do I use `payload.Opportunity.QuoteLineItems.*QuoteLineItem` for each Settings collection?

Comment: Ok, that use case seems a good match for a foreach. The expression is for use as the collection expression in the foreach. I don't know that Settings is in the context of this question.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of the usage in the foreach collection expression.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I have another issue with the string to number / integer conversion can you please help help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666312/convert-the-string-to-integer-or-number