# Convert the string to integer or number

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

How can I convert the string in to the number/integer inside the transfor dataweave. I tried the below

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Coercions
output application/json
---
{
   "quoteId" : vars.setQuoteOppRecIds.Id,
   "productCode" : payload.ServiceTypeCode,
   "axSequenceNumber" : vars.counter as :number,
   "phaseLevel" : payload.PhaseLevel as :number,
   "activeInSOW" : if(payload.PhaseLevelActivateInSOW == "Yes") (toBoolean("true")) else (toBoolean("false")),
   "phaseLevelProject" : payload.PhaseLevelProject
}
```

But I get the error like `Invalid input ':', expected` } `or ',' for the object expression. (line 8, column 41):` I tried to string to boolean using the toBoolean function and itseems to be working fine.  Can anyone please tell me what is that I am missing with the string to integer/number conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for conversion in DW 2 is different. The Code you used is from dw 1. Adding references to type conversions in dw 2 below and fixed your DW script as well.

> https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.1/dataweave-types

```
 %dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Coercions
output application/json
---
{
   "quoteId" : vars.setQuoteOppRecIds.Id,
   "productCode" : payload.ServiceTypeCode,
   "axSequenceNumber" : vars.counter as Number,
   "phaseLevel" : payload.PhaseLevel as Number,
   "activeInSOW" : if(payload.PhaseLevelActivateInSOW == "Yes") (toBoolean("true")) else (toBoolean("false")),
   "phaseLevelProject" : payload.PhaseLevelProject
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you so much.. Can you please suggest how I can convert the values to Integer  for the fields with decimal value ` "unitPrice": payload.UnitPrice as Integer  ` and it throws error like  `Unable to resolve reference of: `Integer`.`

Comment: Can you share the input value you are referring to here

Comment: ""Cannot coerce String (2,854.50) to Number 16|    "salesPriceCustomer":

Comment: I have the 2,854.50 as string I wanted to convert it to the Integer but that where it is throwing the error

Comment: This DW will work, i tried with multiple combinations and tested it in DW playground. `payload.UnitPrice as Number {format: "#,#.##"}`
**upvote if it helps**